Excel formula help-Caulculating dates
How do I calculate a date, 250 days away excluding Nov 16 - May 1 each year?  Date from world be in 1 cell and would need date 250 days away to populate in another cell (excluding the winter months)
Cannot determine a formula

Using WorkDay.Int and REDUCE SEQUENCE to create the array of holidays:
=WORKDAY.INTL(E5,250,"0000000",REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(10,,YEAR(E5)),LAMBDA(z,y,VSTACK(z,SEQUENCE(DATE(y+1,4,30)-DATE(y,11,16)+1,,DATE(y,11,16))))))

This assumes that the only days "Off" would be those between those dates.

